# Funai TV/Monitor

Tags: display, hdmi, tv

So I hooked up a 19" Funai (TV monitor) to my PC so I can have a big screen.  I am 61 and not uber computer savvy. Every time I turn the PC on I have to DC the cable and re plug it in the monitor because I get a message that this TV does not support the resolution.  After I replug it, it works fine until I have to restart or sometimes when it goes into sleep mode. It doesn't matter what resolution I choose, I get the same message. The cable I used was the same one on the small monitor I had before. What can I do?  I used to have this monitor hooked up and it never did that before.

Comment: What is the computer model and the type of connection you're using?  What's the Funai model?  Without more information, people can only guess.  One possibility is that the proper resolution for the TV requires a driver that gets loaded during startup and for some reason, the computer isn't rechecking what's connected after the driver becomes available.  Your physically reconnecting it forces it to take another look.  If it used to work and now doesn't, something changed (update? corruption? hardware problem?)

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into a similar problem, the fix for me was to force 720p, as the default was 1080p, and the TV only supported 1080i. Using the i variant of the resolution was unusable for a computer monitor.

the I stands for "Interlaced"
the P stands for "Progressive"